# Creating a binary search for use in a templated std list

Tags: c++, list, templates, binary-search

```
template<typename C> bool binary_search(list<C>& a, C val) {
    typename list <C>::iterator it;
    typename list <C>::iterator it2;
    typename list <C>::iterator it3;

    size_t elements = a.size();

    for (it = a.begin(), it3 = a.end(); it != it3; ) {
        //find middle element
        elements = elements / 2;
        for (it2 = it; it2 < elements; it2++) {
        }

        if (*it2 < val)
            *it = *it2;
        else if (*it2 > val)
            *it3 = *it2;
        else if (*it2 = val)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Hello! I am having trouble implementing this search function.
`val` in the parameters is the value we are searching for.

when I try to compile the code I get

```
error C2676: binary '<': 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>'
does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

This error occurs at:
`for (it2 = it; it2 < elements; it2++)`

also is there a better way to find the middle element?

Comment: Please add a code comment that shows which line the error refers to.

Comment: I guess the error refers to `it2 < elements`: you can't compare iterator and integer. Anyway, you can't do a `O(log(list size))` binary search over a doubly-linked list.

Comment: @fas It depends on which operations you count. If you count only comparisons, but not iterator advancements, logarithmic complexity is possible.

Comment: If you don’t count comparisons either, it can be O(1)! Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

`elements` holds the index of the last element you want to check.
`it2` is an iterator. `operator<` is not defined for those types. You can use `it` and `elements` to create an iterator to make comparisons possible.

```
size_t elements = a.size();

    for (it = a.begin(), it3 = a.end(); it != it3; ) {
        //find middle element
        elements = elements / 2;
        auto end = std::next(it, elements); // added iterator

        for (it2 = it; it2 != end; it2++) { // use added iterator
        }

        if (*it2 < val)
            *it = *it2;
        else if (*it2 > val)
            *it3 = *it2;
        else if (*it2 = val)   // note: this assigns val to *it2, probably a bug
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is not a good way to solve this lol, but this is my final version and works for my current assignment.

```
template<typename C> bool binary_search(list<C>& a, C val) {
    typename list <C>::iterator it;
    typename list <C>::iterator it2;
    typename list <C>::iterator it3 = a.end();

    size_t elements = a.size();
    size_t i = 0;

    for (it = a.begin(), it3--; it != it3; ) {
        //find middle element
        elements = elements / 2;
        for (it2 = it, i = 0; i < elements; it2++, i++) {
        }

        if (*it2 < val)
            it = it2;
        else if (*it2 > val)
            it3 = it2;
        else if (*it2 = val)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks to fas for pointing out what was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

To move an iterator by a number of places you can use [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance):

```
elements = elements / 2;
it2 = it;
std::advance(it2, elements);
```

Note however that performing a binary search on a `std::list` is unlikely to be efficient unless you have a very expensive comparison function. If you want random access you should use `std::vector` instead. `std::vector`'s iterators also allow you to just add numbers to them without using `std::advance`:

```
elements = elements / 2;
it2 = it + elements;
```

I assume you are implementing binary search as an exercise but if not note that the standard library does have a binary search function it just has a non obvious name: [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)